# Which is a good method for Desktop & web application integration?

Tags: c#, php, web-applications, desktop-application

I have designed a desktop application in c# and web application in php. my desktop application requests data by calling php file and some portion of desktop application showing web forms using web browser control. both process takes too much time. is there any other method speed up this two processes

Answer (score 2):

I would write your PHP app so that it has a RESTful API available that the C# application can connect to.  In this way, you can use a technology like WCF to communicate to your web-based API and use C# in your desktop app to present and work with the data being managed in the PHP app.

You're looking at going back about 15 years to the client-server architectures...  not a bad thing, but all of the lessons we learned then are going to be applicable to you now.

Answer (score 1):

You might could implement something with Adobe AIR.

[Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/)